# Anchor replace with '#id1' , '#id2' , '#id3' ... Sphinx

Tags: anchor, python-sphinx

I named using number in rst file but after building it the anchor is replaced with '#id1', '#id2', '#id3' ....

I need to name the anchor using only number....but I don't know how...

Here is my rst file.

Actual Code

```
*************
Screen(HTS)
*************

Quote
=============

1101
------------------
.. raw:: html
    :file: _static/1101.html

1151
------------------
.. raw:: html
    :file: _static/1151.html

1152
------------------
.. raw:: html
    :file: _static/1152.html

1103
------------------
.. raw:: html
    :file: _static/1103.html
```

Comment: If only you pasted actual code, and not an image of code, then I could easily copy and paste an answer for you. But you didn't, so I won't.

Comment: Sorry for that, I edited my post following your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the underlines and overlines must be the same length as the text.

Unfortunately you want anchors that start with numbers, but Sphinx does not support this. You could instead use an arbitrary anchor that starts with a string. See the documentation for [Cross-referencing arbitrary locations with `:ref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role). Here's an example.

```
***********
Screen(HTS)
***********

Quote
=====

.. _section-1101:

1101
----
```