# Can Sphinx be set up to automatically create bookmarks based on the heading number (not text)?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a large error reference manual which is being converted so as to host on readthedocs using Sphinx.  I'd like to be able to refer users using a permanent bookmark based on a section number (not heading text), as this is what is returned in the error code from the software.  I have something like:

```
This has a chapter heading automatically numbered to give 1.
============================================================

This has a section heading automatically numbered to give 1.1
-------------------------------------------------------------

- This has no section heading as it's in a list, but is ideally 
where I want to send people using the number 1.1.1.  If that's 
too tricky, then a link to the number of the section (1.1) is fine.
```

I'd like to be able to automagically produce bookmarks which are based on the
section's **number**, not its heading text:

```
You got error code 1.1.1 so you need to go to:
www.mysite.readthedocs.io/blah/blah.html#bookmark1.1
```

Does anyone know if/how this can be accomplished without manually creating custom bookmarks for every section? Thanks in advance :)

PS - suggestions that mean that I need to know what the automatically numbered section number will be aren't going to work (eg: [Anchor replace with '#id1' , '#id2' , '#id3' ... Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180511/anchor-replace-with-id1-id2-id3-sphinx) )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anchor replace with '#id1' , '#id2' , '#id3' ... Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180511/anchor-replace-with-id1-id2-id3-sphinx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Steve, but it doesn't.  I don't want to have to manually name the bookmarks as in that example (I can't even see the numbers in the rst as they're all added by the sectnum directive!).  I just want to be able to follow a link to the automatically-numbered section, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood the requirements, but to me it sounds like the [`:numref:` role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-numref) might be helpful in this case.

```
.. toctree::
    :numbered:
```

```
.. _ping:

Ping
====

See :numref:`section "{name}" ({number}) <ping>`.


.. _pong:

Pong
====

See :numref:`section "{name}" ({number}) <pong>`.
```

Comment: @user2662404 Does that answer the question?