# Is there a way to number text items using RST and Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I want to automatically assign numbers to certain parts of an RST file. Say, I have an RST file that contains sections and subsection which describes a list of tasks across all sections, such as **Task 1, Task 2, and so on.**
Is there a way I can define a `task_number` variable that I can use instead of typing '1, 2, etc'? So that when I compile the document, Sphinx read the RST file and assigns a number from **1 to n** based on the order in which the tasks appear in the RST.

Something similar to this:

```
Section Title
=============

Some text here

A Subsection
------------

Task :task_number: 
Description of task 1.

Some more text...

Another Subsection
------------------

Task :task_number: 
Description of Task 2.
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Section Title

Some text here

A Subsection

Task 1 
Description of task 1.

Some more text...

Another Subsection

Task 2 
Description of Task 2.

and so on...
```

Comment: Maybe [`:numref:`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html?highlight=numbered#role-numref)

Comment: Question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/62936118/407651

Comment: Other possible lead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60542779/11138259

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but the `:numref:` option has not been able to solve the issue, and question question by @Lisdengard has no answer yet [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62936118)

Comment: For better control, I believe your best bet is to write a custom _directive_. One that could get numbered similar to how figures, tables, code listings, etc. are numbered.